# Powershell Format Arrays to two dimensional Arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, automation

i had a problem a few days ago where my script that is supposed to extract all hostnames from an AD OU and then check for the space used and free space on disks for every single host. Since this is the first time i do something with powershell i ran into many problems. The Problem that i got now is that the script cant find the hostnames listed in an array. I think i found out why it wont work because it uses the wrong hostname.
Error message i get for every hostname:

```
Write-Warning : Es wurde kein Positionsparameter gefunden, der das Argument "@{Name=BUCHHOLZMVZ}" akzeptiert.
In Zeile:16 Zeichen:5
+     Write-Warning "Server " $server "nicht erreichbar"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Warning], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteWarningCommand
```

When i only use the command to get all hostnames of all servers i get:

```
Name           
----           
someserver
someserver1
someserver2
(and so on...)
```

Here is the script:

```
$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=ServerOU, DC=somedomain, DC=somedomain, DC=somedomain" | Select-Object Name

$allDisks = foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    try {
    Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $server -Filter DriveType=3 -ErrorAction Stop | 
        Select-Object @{'Name'='ComputerName'; 'Expression'={$server}},
            DeviceID, 
            @{'Name'='Size'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}}, 
            @{'Name'='Freespace'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}}
            }
    catch {
    Write-Warning "Server " $server "nicht erreichbar"
    Continue
    }
            
}
$allDisks |Export-Csv C:\Servers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Use `select-object -expand name` in your first line. You only need the name values for the rest of your code

Comment: What is the question (also looking to the title)? It looks that  your diagnose is correct, this is probably not a PowerShell problem. Apparently the concerned server does simply not respond, is not online or doesn't even exit (if it is in AD, it doesn't mean it exist). Try to exclude PowerShell/WMI from the issue by connecting to the concerned server an other way. E.g. `Computer Management --> Computer Management (local), Right click --> Connect to another computer.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following for your first line:

```
$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=ServerOU, DC=somedomain, DC=somedomain, DC=somedomain" |
    Select-Object -Expand Name
```

Using `Select-Object` without `-Expand` or `-ExpandProperty` outputs an object that ***contains properties and values***. If you only want to output values of the selected properties you must use `-Expand` or member access (`$servers.Name`).